# How to combine Filter and IF-Statements in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, filterfunction

**Problem**
I have two sheets.

- Sheet 1: Is supposed to Contain my Dashboard.
- Sheet 2: Contains a table with three columns, starting at row 16

So what I want to do is

1. type in a String in 'Sheet 1'!$B$2, have the formular look for that value in Sheet 2, and return all three columns.
2. If 'Sheet 1'!$B$2 is empty, I would like to show all columns and rows of Sheet

Here is what I tried: `=IF(isblank($B$2), 'Sheet 2'!A16, FILTER('Sheet 2'!A16:A$1000, 'Sheet 2'!$C16:$C$1000=$B$1))`
This works does the trick for Nr. 1, but not for Nr. 2. It only shows the first row obviously.

If I pull the formular down the rows, Nr. 2 works, but Nr. 1 does not. The error it gives me is `REF - Array Result was not expanded, because it would override data in F16`. F16 is the column, the formular is in.

[Here is a sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11wJ9lc049ZMS3Vdu6Hyb40Y5emsWXciabawfcZ2XNjw/edit?usp=sharing)

Can anyone advice?

Comment: can you share a sample sheet please

Comment: Of course!
There you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11wJ9lc049ZMS3Vdu6Hyb40Y5emsWXciabawfcZ2XNjw/edit?usp=sharing

Try tiping in "Name 1" in the criteria or just leave it blank to get all data available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case formula will look like this:

```
=IF(isblank($B$1), ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet2!A16:D1000), 
FILTER(Sheet2!A16:A$1000, Sheet2!$C16:$C$1000=$B$1))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! 
This works with one little addition: It must be "Sheet2!A16:D$1000" in the Filter condition.